# Drools 6.4.0 rule inheritance - multiple rules extends one parent

Tags: drools

I am trying to package multiple drl files each one has multiple rules extending same parent rule BaseRule.

Getting **NullPointerException** while calling

```
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(file), ResourceType.DRL);
```

Looks like the logic used below is not correct in `KnowledgeBuilderImpl - sortRulesByDependency()`

```
    for (RuleDescr ruleDescr : packageDescr.getRules()) {
        if (ruleDescr.isQuery()) {
            queries.add(ruleDescr);
        } else if (!ruleDescr.hasParent()) {
            roots.add(ruleDescr);
        } else {
            if (pkg.getRule(ruleDescr.getParentName()) != null) {
                // The parent of this rule has been already compiled
                compiledRules.add(ruleDescr.getParentName());
            }
            List<RuleDescr> childz = children.get(ruleDescr.getParentName());
            if (childz == null) {
                childz = new ArrayList<RuleDescr>();
                children.put(ruleDescr.getParentName(), childz);
            }
            childz.add(ruleDescr);
        }
    }

    for (String compiledRule : compiledRules) {
        List<RuleDescr> childz = children.remove( compiledRule );
        roots.addAll( childz );
    }
```

`compiledRules` list contains `BaseRule` name multiple times because more than one rule extending `BaseRule`.

After first time remove, next time it is going to return NULL and that will cause **NullPointerException** in `roots.addAll`

Any idea why there is no check to avoid this case?

Comment: Probably the author of this code didn't think of this case. -- SO is not the place to discuss bugs in Drools. There are Drools user lists, there is JIRA error reporting for Drools. Prepare a complete example and present your case there.